# How can I allow a user to send private messages but prevent other users from sending that user a private message?

Tags: privatemsg

I have a "system" user that sends "Welcome to the website" private messages as well as announcements to users.  I am able to send these messages via rules; however, I don't want users to be able to reply to these messages.

I tried disabling private messages for the system user but that option disables both the receiving and sending of private messages (I checked-- if private messages are disabled for a user, no private message can be mailed from that user using rules).

I don't need a solution that is bulletproof; hiding the reply form on the private message view screen is sufficient.  However, I dug through the private message module code and was unable to find any way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. The pm_block_user module has settings that allow for role-based configurations for who is allowed to write whom. However, it is only possible to add positive rules. Meaning, you wold need to add all your users into a normal role that the system user is not part of and then allow users of that role to write users of that role.
2. Implement [hook_privatemsg_block_message()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.api.php/function/hook_privatemsg_block_message/7-1) and block the system user id.

You're welcome to provide option two as a patch in the main module (e.g. allow to choose a system user whom you can't write/reply and is maybe also themed differently). This is an often requested feature.